# Python: Reproduce nested Excel Pivot table in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

**Question:**

Is it possible to display pandas report in exactly same format like excel?

**Current situation:**

I am trying to automate excel report using python.

Excel report is in following format:

[image: http://pbpython.com/images/excel-pivot-example.png]

I am using below code to generate pivot table in pandas:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 df = pd.read_excel("sales-funnel.xlsx")
 table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Manager","Rep","Product"],
           values=["Price","Quantity"],
           aggfunc=[np.sum],fill_value=0)`
```

I would like to get report similar to excel due to huge size of data. Pandas report will be difficult to analyze in excel.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "in exactly same format"?

Comment: I want pandas report to look like attached excel report image.I am automating excel report using python so keeping excel format intact is the  challenge.

Comment: If you can manually create the pandas dataframe that you're looking for and show it here (copy paste in text form), we can help you. But an image is too vague, it's impossible to tell what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to save Pandas table as Pivot Table in .xlsx file? You'll never do it. There're libraries to save, edit and read Excel files, but there's no tool in them to work with Pivot Tables.